# Multivariate polynomials at bounded evens

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, roots, interpolation

**Univariate polynomials**

Given $n$, is there a degree $cn^{c'}$ polynomial $p(x)\in\Bbb R[x]$ and a degree $dn^{d'}$ polynomial $q(x)\in\Bbb R[x]$ with fixed $c,c',d,d'>0$ such that $$m\in\Bbb Z:|2m|<2^n\implies p(2m)=0\mbox{ and }p(2m+1)\neq0$$$$m\in\Bbb Z:|2m|<2^n\implies q(2m)\neq0 \mbox{ and }q(2m+1)=0?$$

Answer (score 1):

For the first pair of conditions: $p(x)$ would be divisible by the polynomial $$x\prod_{m=1}^{2^{n-1}-1}(x^2-4m^2).$$
Indeed, the first condition gives a list of zeroes: $0,2,4, \dots 2m,\dots,2^{n}-2$ and their opposites. This means the polynomial is divisible by each of $x\pm 2m$, hence by their product, since any pair of these are coprime.

The degree of the latter polynomial is $2^n-1$, so the answer is `no`.

Similarly, for the second pair of conditions, the degree can't be  $O(n^d)$ since it would be (at least)  exponential in $n$.

Comment: @Turbo: See my updated answer. Is that clearer?

Comment: It's simpler than interpolation, as the latter consists in requiring prescribed values at given points. Here the prescribed values are all 0.

Comment: I am unable to post new questions due to system block. So I updated current question with bivariate polynomials.

Comment: What happens in general for multivariate polynomials? This question is also interesting?

Comment: @Turbo:I suppose $x,y$ take integer values? Anyway, I think it's quite tough, as it comes to a question of diophantine geometry.

Comment: Right about $x,y$ integer values. Please leave your thoughts on diophantine geometric approach.

Comment: I'm sorry to say I don't know really much about the subject. Of course, if  I have any idea, I'll leave it here.

Comment: Even reason on problem being diophantine could be insightful.